# How to use GETPIVOTDATA correctly

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am having difficulty when I try to refer to a specific cell reference in my pivot table.

```
Dim SelectionNum As Integer
    
LastRow = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CMAPivot").TableRange2.Rows.Count

 SelectionNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(4, LastRow)
 MsgBox(GETPIVOTDATA("CLM_NR",CMAPivot!$A$[SelectionNum]))   ' this is the line I get a syntax error on
```

I have also tried:

```
 MsgBox(GETPIVOTDATA("CLM_NR",$A$[SelectionNum])) as well as
 MsgBox(GETPIVOTDATA("CLM_NR","CMAPivot"!$A$[SelectionNum]))
```

Regardless I get a syntax error on my cell reference $A$[SelectionNum] (which I have also tried w/o the brackets)

I am basically trying to randomly select a claim number for auditing purposes. Once I successfully can reference the CLM_NR, I will write the value to a cell on my spreadsheet.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Please edit your post to upload a screenshot of pivottable.

Answer (score 0):

- `GETPIVOTDATA` is used to get data in data body area in the pivottable.
- If I were right, you try to get a random value of a row field.
- The rows count of header and page fields (`4` in your code) may various.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim SelectionNum As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long, RowCnt As Long
    Dim ColRng As Range
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CMAPivot")
        Set ColRng = .TableRange2.Columns(1)
        RowCnt = ColRng.Cells.Count - .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    End With
    SelectionNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(RowCnt + 1, ColRng.Cells.Count)
    MsgBox ColRng.Cells(SelectionNum)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You set me in the right direction. This is what worked:

```
'Declare Variables
Dim SelectionNum As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim pt As PivotTable
        
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("CMAPivot")
LastRow = pt.TableRange2.Rows.Count

SelectionNum = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(2, LastRow - 1)     

Range("X4").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(SelectionNum, 1)
```